# Validating nuSoap against WS-i 's BP2406 (Binding required true)

Tags: php, web-services, nusoap

Thr issue the brings me here today is the following. We've had a fully funcitonal  WS  for a few years now. This is being used by different customer but we are targeting a sale to a new prospect who need our Web service to be WS-i compliant.

I used PHP and nuSoap to build the WS and I use SoapUi which uses the Ws-i test tools to validate compliance. Vaidation fails with this one error
---BP2406

```
SOAPBody ({http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/}body):
required=null
use=encoded
encodingStyles=[http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/]
namespaceURI=http://mydomain/webservice.php
Element Location:
  lineNumber=134
```

and on line 134 and 135 of my WSDL

```
<binding name="MyWSBinding" type="tns:MyWsPortType">
<soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
```

Has anyone got a clue on how to set the binding right to be compliant using php's nuSoap . Any word of advice will be helpful.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I validated .  If anyone evr comes around this error . The fix is adding 'rpc'/'literal' or false  as parameters to the $server->register() method. 
Since this parameters are optional , you WS will work , but wont validate if not specified.